# How to trigger bitbucket pipeline on branch creation or deletion

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, cicd

What is the bitbucket-pipelines equivalent of github's?

```
on:
  create:

on:
  delete:
```

Comment: is it possible to trigger a pipeline on delete event? delete of any branch or say feature branch, is it possible to capture that event. This event is there in webhook